# Css media query not working properly at chrome and safari

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to make my horizontal menu transform to vertical when page resized or screen size is below 500 pixes but after making changes i realised my menu behaving like this only in edge and ie not in safari or chrome. At safari menu is shown vertically whatever the size is, and at chrome menu is shown horizontally whatever the size is. How can i make it behave same like in ie and edge?

Below is my index html and css file:

```css
/* CSS Document */

body {
  font-family: 'Happy Monkey', cursive;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.top {
  position: relative;
}

.banner-home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 237px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url("../images/faruk-yeni2.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.baslik-altcizgi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 235px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #111111;
}

.baslik-yazi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 255px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 30px
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 550px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F2B544;
  background-color: #2C0E40;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0D0D0D;
  color: #FFFFFF
}

nav ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.image-one {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.image-two {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.image-three {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.art-one-home-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
}

.art-two-home-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
}

.art-three-home-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  nav ul li {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .feature-images {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ömer Faruk Durusoy</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepage.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Happy+Monkey&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="top">
        <div class="banner-home"></div>
        <div class="baslik-altcizgi"></div>
        <div class="baslik-yazi">
          My name
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section class="feature-images">
        <div class="image-one">
          <img src="images/javascript.png" alt="Javascript">
          <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
        </div>
        <div class="image-two">
          <img src="images/html5.png" alt="html5">
          <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
        </div>
        <div class="image-three">
          <img src="images/java.png" alt="Java">
          <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <article class="art-one-home">
        <div class="art-one-home-img"></div>
        <h2>This is the article one</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </article>
      <article class="art-two-home">
        <div class="art-two-home-img"></div>
        <h2>This is the article one</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      </article>
      <article class="art-three-home">
        <div class="art-three-home-img"></div>
        <h2>This is the article one</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </article>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am using chrome and the nav is collapsing to a single column when the screen is less than 500px.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King interesting, why it may be behaving like this at my browser? i even tried to refresh with ctrl+f5.

Comment: Try to disable plugins like AdBlock that you might have in Chrome, it works fine for me.

Comment: disabled all the addons but still same :(

Comment: How are you resizing chrome? Are you using the Inspector or just resizing the window? When I resize my browser window it doesn't change (stops at 500px), but it does when I use the inspector and set the numerical values (499 or less) it does.

Comment: @Faruk Could [Chrome's minimum width limit](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/5443420?hl=en) be preventing the breakpoint from triggering? Does anything happen if you use the device mode in the developer tools to force the width below 500px?

Comment: ok sorry guys, i didnt even know a device mode exists, i was manually resizing the chrome but when i clicked device mode it collapsed like expected. It was working on ie and edge when i manually resized it, anyways chrome is working this way but desktop safari is weirdly showing the menu in column even at full screen size, any ideas on that?

Comment: Depending on the version of safari you're targeting, you might need to prefix the flex property: `display: -webkit-flex;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. 
First declare classes or css properties to elements then it will do changes as per the screen size.

```
      nav ul {
        display: flex;
      }
      nav ul li {
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0px;
      }
      .feature-images {
        display: flex;
      }

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  nav ul li {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .feature-images {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

Comment: when i make these changes edge and ie starts to behave like chrome and safari stays same (vertical always). This is not what i wanted. I want all of them act like ie/edge which is collapsing to single column.